# getting network issue in Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic) for USB WiFi adaptor (Ralink MT7601U (148f:7601))

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, 22.04, ralink

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 in my old desktop. Everything is working as expected except the WiFi.

**WiFi is showing low network strength and getting disconnected if i'm taking the router more than 5 feet away.**

I tried every possible solution provided in this place but nothing worked for me.

I also tried to make driver and install it, but that also didn't work.
I tried the same usb wifi adaptor in windows devices, everything worked as expected.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Its helpful if you're specific as to what problems you tried; eg. for old hardware I often find the older kernel stack option (ie. LTS releases have kernel stack choice; GA kernel being 5.15 instead of 6.2) can often work better; but you didn't mention what you actually tried. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html

Comment: @guiverc I'm using USB wifi adaptor to access internet. Even if the router is near to my PC, it was showing low network signal. and sometimes getting disconnected without any reason. Hope I"m able to explain it properly.

Comment: What solutions have you tried is not explained; you mention "*every possible solution provided in this place*" and I've specifically mentioned trying the GA kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (ie. 5.15 kernel instead of 6.2, given old hardware) yet you don't mention?. What chipset are you using [step 3.1 or *Device Recognition and Operation* the most useful](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide); as once you've worked out the chipset involved, you have what Linux requires to make it work in my experience)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)